# Variable scoping error mixing keras with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Keras for text classification using a CNN. However, the keras code seems to greatly underperform the equivalent tensorflow code. As a result, I've been trying to swap out bits of Keras code to see where the bottleneck is. However, I'm getting the following error suggesting that I'm reusing a variable_scope:

```
ValueError: Variable conv_maxpool_1/W already exists, disallowed.
Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

File "foo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 651, in call
             return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
File "foo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 603, in __call__ output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
```

I'm using the functional api and a `Lambda` layer to get the convolution layer:

```
def get_conv_pool_layer(embeddings, embedding_size, filter_size, num_filters, sequence_length):

    def _get_conv_pool(embeddings):
        with tf.variable_scope("conv_maxpool_%s" % filter_size) as scope:
            filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]
            W = tf.get_variable("W",
                                shape=filter_shape,
                                initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0, 0.1))
            b = tf.get_variable("b", shape=[num_filters], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                embeddings,
                W,
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='VALID')

            h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name=scope.name)
            return tf.nn.max_pool(
                    h,
                    ksize=[1, sequence_length - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                    padding='VALID',
                    name="pool")

    return Lambda(_get_conv_pool)(embeddings)
```